# QStyledItemDelegate disabling button in last column moves selection to next row

Tags: qt, selection, pyside, qtableview, qstyleditemdelegate

**Setup description**

- Table in PySide created with
  QMainWindow - > QWidget -> QTableView -> TableModel (QAbstractTableModel) -> array[]
- For second and third column is created ButtonDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate)
- buttons toggle value in the first column - but butons must be separate for specific reason in my application (toggling with one button is not a solution)
- button with value of the first column is "hidden"
- only whole single row is selected (important in my application where I'm separately showing detailed data on the selected row)

**Detailed description of functionality**

- Buttons in my application don't necesserily toggle value. Easiest to explaining fonctionality of my application is something like configuration list.
- Initially in the list are generic items which can be selected and the two buttons are "+" (add/select) and "-" (remove/deselect).
- Some items can be added only once, in that case the buttons are really only toggling the item selection. If not selected only the button "+" is show and if selected only button "-" is shown.
- Some items can be added multiple times. In that case initially the item is unseleted. Presing "+" selects the item, shows "-" buton, but button "+" is still shown, as the item can be added multiple times. When pressed "+" once again, the next row with the same item is added, again with both "+" and "-" shown. Then pressing "-" works in reverse way, removing row where "-" is pressed until last item of the same type, where "-" results in unselected item. Therefore function of +/- is content dependent.
- There few reasons I decided to have buttons in separate columns - keep possibility to sort based on selection state, header to show "Add" for "+" and "Remove" for "-"

**Problem description**

- when button in last column is disabled (pushing False button and then True button), the selection moves to next row - should remain in the same
- also, probably the showing and hiding of active button should be done in paint (instead of the openPersistentEditor). I was looking in the documentation and examples from google to find way how to, but still I haven't figured it out. If you could show me how, I would appreciate it. Also if you have link to some good tutorial on this topic (paint) I would be glad, because still I'm not getting how to use it.

**Minimal functioning example:**

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QAbstractItemView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import  QTableView, QWidget, QStyledItemDelegate, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex, QAbstractTableModel, QItemSelectionModel

class TrueButtonDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)    

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index) # this should be somewhere else, not in paint

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QPushButton('True', parent)
        editor.setEnabled(False)
        editor.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        return editor
    
    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if not index.data():
            editor.setText('True')
            editor.setEnabled(True)
            editor.setFlat(False)
            
        else:
            editor.setText('')
            editor.setEnabled(False)
            editor.setFlat(True)
    
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, True, role=Qt.EditRole)
        
    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.commitData.emit(self.sender())    
    
    
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.Type.Wheel:
            event.setAccepted(False)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class FalseButtonDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)    

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index) # this should be somewhere else, not in paint

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QPushButton('False', parent)
        editor.setEnabled(True)
        editor.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        return editor
    
    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if index.data():
            editor.setText('False')
            editor.setEnabled(True)
            editor.setFlat(False)
            
        else:
            editor.setText('')
            editor.setEnabled(False)
            editor.setFlat(True)
    
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, False, role=Qt.EditRole)
        
    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.commitData.emit(self.sender())    
    
    
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.Type.Wheel:
            event.setAccepted(False)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, localData=[[]], parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.modelData = localData

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return "Row " + str(section)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return 3

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.modelData)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            return self.modelData[row]
    
    def setData(self, index, value = None, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        self.modelData[row] = value

        index = self.index(row, 0)
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index) 
        index = self.index(row, 1)
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index) 
        index = self.index(row, 2)
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index) 

        return True

app = QApplication()

data = [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]

model = TableModel(data)

tableView = QTableView()
tableView.setModel(model)
selectionModel = QItemSelectionModel(model)
tableView.setSelectionModel(selectionModel)
tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, FalseButtonDelegate(tableView))
tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, TrueButtonDelegate(tableView))
tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
tableView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)


widget = QWidget()
widget.horizontalHeader = tableView.horizontalHeader()
widget.horizontalHeader.setStretchLastSection(True)
widget.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
widget.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(1,1,1,1)
widget.mainLayout.addWidget(tableView)
widget.setLayout(widget.mainLayout)

mainWindow = QMainWindow()
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(widget)
mainWindow.setGeometry(0, 0, 380, 300)
mainWindow.show()


exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: There are a few problems with your implementation (other than the `openPersistentEditor()`), but the most important is that, since `setModelData()` is called whenever the index is changed, your code changes the model every time one of those cells loses focus (try using tab and shift-tab and you'll see). You said that your buttons must be separated: can you clarify why do you need that? Besides, instead of using two separate columns and widgets, why don't you use a single widget with two buttons?

Comment: Yes, moving with arrows also press the button. That is bad. How can it be fixed? Rest of your question I answered in section Detailed description of functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that disabling the widget automatically sets the focus to the next available widget in the focus chain.

The actual behavior is based on the QAbstractItemView's re-implementation of [`focusNextPrevChild`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusNextPrevChild), which creates a "virtual" QKeyPressEvent with a tab (or backtab) key that is sent to the `keyPressEvent()` handler.

By default, this results in calling the table view's reimplementation of [`moveCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#moveCursor), which focuses on the next selectable item (the first item in the next row in your case).

A possible workaround for this would be to use a subclass of QTableView and override `focusNextPrevChild()`; in this way you can *first* check if the *current* widget is a button and a child of the viewport (meaning it's one of your editors), and eventually just return True without doing anything else:

```
class TableView(QTableView):
    def focusNextPrevChild(self, isNext):
        if isNext:
            current = QApplication.focusWidget()
            if isinstance(current, QPushButton) and current.parent() == self.viewport():
                return True
        return super().focusNextPrevChild(isNext)
```

Unfortunately, this won't resolve a major issue with your implementation.

Implementing such complex systems like yours, requires some special care and knowledge about how Qt views work, and the main problem is related to the fact that `setModelData()` can be triggered by various reasons; one of them is whenever the current index of the view changes. This can happen with keyboard navigation (tab/backtab, arrows, etc), but also when the mouse changes the current selection: you can see this in your UI by clicking and keeping the mouse button pressed on an item on the first column, and then begin to drag the mouse on items that have buttons; since that operation changes the selection model, this also triggers the current index change, and consequentially the `setModelData` of the delegate, since the persistent editor is opened.

A better implementation (which also doesn't require separate delegates) implies knowing whether the current index corresponds to the "true" or "false" column. As long as you know the column used to show contents when the value is `True`, then setting the value and showing the buttons is just a matter of comparing those three values:

```
        value = index.data()
        trueColumn = index.column() == self.TrueColumn
        if value == trueColumn:
            # we are in the column that should show the widget
        else:
            # we are in the other column (whatever it is)
```

Setting the data when the button is pressed follows the same concept; if the button is in the "true" column (the one used to set the value to `False`), set it to False, and vice versa:

```
    model.setData(index, index.column() != self.TrueColumn, Qt.EditRole)
```

Then, some further adjustments are also required:

- to avoid focus problems, you can make the editor ignore mouse events by setting the attribute `Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents`, and ignore keyboard focus by setting the focus policy to `No.Focus`; then restore the default behavior when the editor is "restored";
- to make the button transparent, use a stylesheet that makes every component invisible: `color: transparent; background: transparent; border: none;`;
- do not open the editor in the paint method, but properly call `openPersistentIndex()` both when the model is set *and* when new rows are added;
- if you want to hide the text of the index, just override [`displayText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#displayText) and return an empty string; in this way you can keep the default paint behavior which shows selected items;

```py
class ButtonDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    TrueColumn = 1
    isClicked = False
    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.isClicked = True
        self.commitData.emit(self.sender())
        self.isClicked = False

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QPushButton(str(index.column() != self.TrueColumn), parent)
        editor.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        return editor

    def eventFilter(self, editor, event):
        if event.type() == event.MouseMove:
            editor.mouseMoveEvent(event)
            event.setAccepted(True)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(editor, event)

    def displayText(self, *args):
        return ''

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.data()
        trueColumn = index.column() == self.TrueColumn
        if value == trueColumn:
            editor.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, False)
            editor.setStyleSheet('')
            editor.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
            if self.isClicked:
                editor.setFocus()
                self.parent().setCurrentIndex(index)
        else:
            editor.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, True)
            editor.setStyleSheet(
                'color:transparent; background: transparent; border: none;')
            editor.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        sender = self.sender()
        if sender:
            model.setData(index, index.column() != self.TrueColumn, Qt.EditRole)


app = QApplication([])

data = [True] * 16

tableView = QTableView()
tableView.setModel(model)
selectionModel = QItemSelectionModel(model)
tableView.setSelectionModel(selectionModel)

delegate = ButtonDelegate(tableView)
tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)
tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate)

tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
tableView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)

def updateEditors(parent, first, last):
    for row in range(first, last + 1):
        tableView.openPersistentEditor(model.index(row, 1))
        tableView.openPersistentEditor(model.index(row, 2))

updateEditors(None, 0, model.rowCount() - 1)
model.rowsInserted.connect(updateEditors)

# ...
```

A further improvement would consider tab navigation, and for this you need to tweak the model *and* the view. With the following modifications, pressing tab only changes between indexes with valid data or active editor:

```
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    tabPressed = False
    def __init__(self, localData=[[]], parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.modelData = localData

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super().flags(index)
        if 0 < index.column() < self.columnCount() and self.tabPressed:
            if (index.column() != 1) == self.modelData[index.row()]:
                flags &= ~(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        return flags

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return "Row " + str(section)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return 3

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.modelData)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.modelData[index.row()]
    
    def setData(self, index, value = None, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        self.modelData[row] = value

        # do not emit dataChanged for each index, emit it for the whole range
        self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(row, 0), self.index(row, 2)) 

        return True


class TableView(QTableView):
    def moveCursor(self, action, modifiers):
        self.model().tabPressed = True
        new = super().moveCursor(action, modifiers)
        self.model().tabPressed = False
        return new


# ...

tableView = TableView()
```

### Update: further options

It occured to me that there is another available alternative: while keeping the two-column requirement, it is possible to have a single delegate, as long as the table has properly set *spans*.

This requests some ingenuity, and a further class (with a proper *user* property set) is required, but it might provide a better result; the trick is to create a custom widget that contains both buttons. Some further adjustments are required too (especially to ensure that the size of the inner widgets is respected whenever the columns are resized).

```py
class Switch(QWidget):
    valueChanged = Signal(bool)
    clicked = Signal()
    _value = False
    def __init__(self, table, column):
        super().__init__(table.viewport())
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.TabFocus)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.spacing = self.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_HeaderGripMargin)
        layout.setSpacing(self.spacing)
        self.buttons = []
        for v in range(2):
            button = QPushButton(str(bool(v)))
            self.buttons.append(button)
            layout.addWidget(button)
            button.setMinimumWidth(10)
            button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.header = table.horizontalHeader()
        self.columns = column, column + 1
        self.updateButtons(False)

        self.header.sectionResized.connect(self.updateSizes)
        self.resizeTimer = QTimer(self, interval=0, singleShot=True, 
            timeout=self.updateSizes)

    @Property(bool, user=True, notify=valueChanged)
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if self._value != value:
            self._value = value
            self.valueChanged.emit(value)
        self.updateButtons(self._value)

    def updateButtons(self, value):
        focused = False
        self.setFocusProxy(None)
        for i, button in enumerate(self.buttons):
            if i != value:
                button.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, False)
                self.setFocusProxy(button)
                button.setStyleSheet('')
            else:
                if button.hasFocus():
                    focused = True
                button.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, True)
                button.setStyleSheet(
                    'color: transparent; background: transparent; border: none;')
        if focused:
            self.setFocus(Qt.MouseFocusReason)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        self.value = bool(self.buttons.index(button))
        self.clicked.emit()

    def updateSizes(self):
        for i, column in enumerate(self.columns):
            size = self.header.sectionSize(column)
            if i == 0:
                size -= self.spacing
            self.layout().setStretch(i, size)
        self.layout().activate()

    def focusNextPrevChild(self, isNext):
        return False

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.updateSizes()


class SwitchButtonDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, *args):
        return ''

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = Switch(self.parent(), index.column())
        def clicked():
            if persistent.isValid():
                index = persistent.model().index(
                    persistent.row(), persistent.column(), persistent.parent())
                view.setCurrentIndex(index)
        view = option.widget
        persistent = QPersistentModelIndex(index)
        editor.clicked.connect(clicked)
        editor.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.commitData.emit(editor))
        return editor

# ...

tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, SwitchButtonDelegate(tableView))

def updateEditors(parent, first, last):
    for row in range(first, last + 1):
        tableView.setSpan(row, 1, 1, 2)
        tableView.openPersistentEditor(model.index(row, 1))
```

---

Of course, the simpler solution is to avoid any editor at all, and *delegate* the painting to the item delegate.

```py
class PaintButtonDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    _pressIndex = _mousePos = None
    def __init__(self, trueColumn=0, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.trueColumn = trueColumn

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        opt = QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(opt, index)
        style = opt.widget.style()
        opt.text = ''
        opt.state |= style.State_Enabled
        style.drawControl(style.CE_ItemViewItem, opt, painter, opt.widget)
        if index.data() == (index.column() == self.trueColumn):
            btn = QStyleOptionButton()
            btn.initFrom(opt.widget)
            btn.rect = opt.rect
            btn.state = opt.state
            btn.text = str(index.column() != self.trueColumn)
            if self._pressIndex == index and self._mousePos in btn.rect:
                btn.state |= style.State_On
            if index == option.widget.currentIndex():
                btn.state |= style.State_HasFocus
            style.drawControl(style.CE_PushButton, btn, painter, opt.widget)

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress:
            if index.data() == (index.column() == self.trueColumn):
                self._pressIndex = index
                self._mousePos = event.pos()
            option.widget.viewport().update()
        elif event.type() == event.MouseMove and self._pressIndex is not None:
            self._mousePos = event.pos()
            option.widget.viewport().update()
        elif event.type() == event.MouseButtonRelease:
            if self._pressIndex == index and event.pos() in option.rect:
                model.setData(index, not index.data(), Qt.EditRole)
            self._pressIndex = self._mousePos = None
            option.widget.viewport().update()
        elif event.type() == event.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
                value = not index.data()
                model.setData(index, value, Qt.EditRole)
                newIndex = model.index(index.row(), self.trueColumn + (not value))
                option.widget.setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
            option.widget.viewport().update()
        return super().editorEvent(event, model, option, index)

# ...

delegate = PaintButtonDelegate(1, tableView)
tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)
tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate)
```

Note that in this case, if you want to keep a valid keyboard (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) navigation, the model also requires adjustments:

```py
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    # ...
    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super().flags(index)
        if 0 < index.column() < 3:
            if index.data() == index.column() - 1:
                flags &= ~Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return flags
```

This unfortunately results in unexpected behavior of the horizontal header, as only the enabled columns will be "highlighted" with some specific styles.

That said, the other important drawback of this approach is that you will completely lose any animation provided by the style: since the style uses *actual* widgets to create visual animations, and the painting is only based on the current QStylOption value, those animations will not be available.

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything works perfectly.
I didn't think it would be so complicated to solve this problem but that is probably beginners optimism.
If you would have some good source to study on this topics of internal working of the Qt, could you please share it?

Comment: @martin_h having two separate delegates makes things a bit more complex, having a single one would help; it just occurred to me that there's a workaround for that: using the table span ([`setSpan()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSpan)) you can use a single QWidget container (with the two buttons) as an editor, which would at least simplify the focus and keyboard navigation. If I've time later I'll update the answer. Unfortunately I don't have specific links to suggest, most of this comes with experience, studying of the documentation and the Qt source code.

Comment: @martin_h see the update.